# How to get the rows position numbers of a table result

Tags: t-sql, select, stored-procedures, row-number

This is my code

```
Select @pos = Pos, @ptsReputacion = isnull(AA.PtsReputacion,0)
    From
    (Select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @ptsReputacion DESC) AS Pos
    , USUARIO.CodUsuario
    , PtsReputacion = (Select isnull(sum(Puntos),0) as Puntos
                        From USUARIO_RANKING_INTERES 
                        Where USUARIO_RANKING_INTERES.CodUsuario = @codUsuario) 
    , USUARIO.CantIntentos as Intentos
    , USUARIO.CantAciertos as Aciertos
    , USUARIO.CantFallos as Fallos
    , isnull(USUARIO.PG,0) as PG
    , isnull(USUARIO.PE,0) as PE
    , isnull(USUARIO.PP,0) as PP
    , isnull(USUARIO.TiempoTotal,0) as TiempoTotal
    From USUARIO) AA
    Where AA.CodUsuario = @codUsuario
```

But it doesn't works because the Pos field has an other value. For example, it gives 2 instead 1.

I want to know how to get the row position number one by one ordered by a variable (because the field is a subquery).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you really want to do something like the below.  I'm using CTEs because that makes it easier to read.

```
WITH BaseQuery AS
(
SELECT
    U.CodUsuario
    , PtsReputacion = (Select isnull(sum(Puntos),0) as Puntos
                    From USUARIO_RANKING_INTERES 
                    Where USUARIO_RANKING_INTERES.CodUsuario = U.CodUsuario) 
    , USUARIO.CantIntentos as Intentos
    , USUARIO.CantAciertos as Aciertos
    , USUARIO.CantFallos as Fallos
    , isnull(USUARIO.PG,0) as PG
    , isnull(USUARIO.PE,0) as PE
    , isnull(USUARIO.PP,0) as PP
    , isnull(USUARIO.TiempoTotal,0) as TiempoTotal
FROM USUARIO U
),
RNQuery AS
(
SELECT
    *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PtsReputacion DESC) AS Pos
FROM
    BaseQuery
)
SELECT 
    @pos = Pos
    , @ptsReputacion = isnull(AA.PtsReputacion,0)
FROM
    RNQuery AS AA
WHERE
    AA.CodUsuario = @codUsuario
```